# zsh: Evaluate array as command

Tags: shell, zsh

It is very useful to be able to use array constructs to compose large, multi-line commands.  For example:

```
declare -a command=(
   somecommand
       -flagA # comment
       -flagB # comment

   # No need for line continuation characters!
   foo/bar/baz.ext

   # Pipe into grep
   || grep fizz buzz # <=== This does not work!
)
```

And it can then be executed as `${command[@]}`.  However, you cannot embed control-flow characters like `&&` or `||` and have them executed correctly.

Is there any way to do this from a ZSH array?

Comment: could you join the array, and then `eval` it?

Comment: The typical approach is to store just the *arguments* in the array, then run `somecommand "${args[@]}"`.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, you don't need explicit continuation characters following `&&` or `||` since a command list can't end with either.

Comment: @ZachRiggle, ...what do you mean by "this"? The code you're describing works perfectly well in zsh, unless you're asking how to have a single array describe a *compound* command. Please be explicit if that's the case.

Comment: ...I'd suggest editing the title to actually be explicit about what you're trying to do -- changing it, f/e, from "Evaluate array as command" to "Include && or || in command from array", if again that describes this question's intent.

Comment: I've updated the example to include piping through grep.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your example isn't a pipe; it's a command list. However, you also don't need implicit line continuations for either `||` or `|`.

```
someCommandArgs=(
    -flagA  # comment
    -flagB  # comment

    foo/bar/baz.ext
)

someCommand "${someCommandArgs[@]}" |
  grep fizz buzz
```

A command cannot end with `|`, so the parser knows the command must continue onto the other line.

The above can be packaged into a single function:

```
myCommand () {
  local -a args=(
      -flagA  # comment
      -flagB  # comment

      foo/bar/baz.ext
  )
  someCommand "${args[@]}" | 
    grep fizz buzz
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(EDIT: there seems to be some edits to the original question after I answered it)

Having to guess as you did not provide sample code, but the `eval` command comes to mind:

```
declare -a command=(
  ls
     -l
   /dev/random
   '||'
   cat -n
     )

echo EXE: ${command[*]}
eval "${command[@]}"
```

- Quoting the metacharacters within the definition is required.
- Use of double quotes on the `eval` becomes quite important
  to automagically quote the `||` and other shell
  metacharacters.

Comment: Using `eval` in this way eliminates the benefits you'd otherwise get from using an array. With an array and **not** using `eval`, you can be confident that one array element == one "word" in the resulting command. `eval` breaks that guarantee, because it combines the array elements into a string and then parses the string as code.

Comment: As a concrete example, try `declare -a command=( printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" )`, and then compare `"${command[@]}"` to `eval "${command[@]}"`.

Comment: As mentioned, `eval` breaks some of the assumptions that make the array composition very convenient to use

Comment: But `eval` is necessary if you are putting syntactic elements like `||` into the array. As with almost all uses of `eval`, though, that seems like not a great idea. Perhaps you can concoct an alternative.

Comment: For sure you need to scrub or deeply control any input to eval as well as watch your quotes for unexpected expansion. Double quoting the expansion goes a long way toward that as each member becomes a single word (providing no self-destructive metacharacters are present). With proper care languages like python or perl are much better positioned to avoid wild expansions.